# Use annotation processor in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, annotation-processor

I have a simple annotation in my processor like following:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.TYPE) @Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface BundleBuilder
{
    // ...
}
```

This works in java files but as soon as I convert my file to kotlin, the import of the annotation is not working anymore. Why?

[image]

What do I need to change to get his annotation working in kotlin as well? From the docs I can see that kotlin is 100% compatible with java annotations so I'm a little bit confused here what's the problem... I would understand if the processor is not working and needs to be adjusted to work with kotlin, but I don't know why the import itself does not work...

The library I'm talking about is here: https://github.com/MFlisar/BundleArgs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `kapt` for annotation processing in your `build.gradle`. After all, clean and rebuild your project so.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

//...

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'com.github.MFlisar.BundleArgs:bundleargs-annotation:1.3'
    kapt 'com.github.MFlisar.BundleArgs:bundleargs-processor:1.3'
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

Comment: I'm using kapt everywhere already for quite some time, this is not the problem, sadly...

Comment: I do above in a sample project, no problem happened and BundleBuilder worked well! :-\

Comment: Try to Invalidate caches and restart the AndroidStudio.